Flutter Web app inside an iframe appears stretched and unscrollable on mobile
I am currently working on a flutter web app, which needs to be embedded into an existing website ideally through an iframe, as we can't access the code of it completely. I can ask them to add little code snippets here and there, but embedding the whole app would be impossible. For testing purposes, I'm currently using a different domain that I can access completely, where I embed the app hosted on our server.
What I'm trying to do is make the height of the iframe change dynamically, as the whole app won't fit on smaller screens. I've followed this article https://medium.com/@ingo.rockel/embedding-a-flutter-web-application-inside-an-iframe-with-a-dynamic-height-66c7197a5c94 and everything works well on desktop. However, the content is stretching crazily on phone browsers and you can't scroll on top of the iframe on tablets either. I'm not quite sure how to solve this. The website is live here https://benjamincorben.com/.
I've tried playing with the scrolling and overflow settings of the iframe, putting the iframe into a div and changing the settings there, but nothing has worked so far.
Here's my current code, that has not been altered that works on desktop properly.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="widgetIframe" width="100%" src="https://asp.zephiros.com/test_lenis/vizitky/index.html" frameborder="0"></iframe> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Add event listener for messages being passed from the iframe
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
      // Check that message being passed is the documentHeight
      if ((typeof e.data === 'string') && (e.data.indexOf('documentHeight') > -1)) {
        var height = e.data.split('documentHeight:')[1];
        height = parseInt(height, 10) + 50;
        
        // Change height of iframe
        document.getElementById('widgetIframe').style.height = height + 'px';
      }
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>

